# Wrap every h1, h2, h3 in a string of HTML in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

I have a string of HTML. I want to take every h1, h2, h3 in it, and wrap it a component called `<TitleWrapper />`.

How can I do this?

**Example**

It's a strange request so here's why it's hard. I'm turning markdown into HTML, which gives me an HTML string. [Here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sindresorhus/awesome-nodejs/master/readme.md) is an example of some of the markdown I'm using.

Right now I'm using [Marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) to translate markdown into HTML. It has a function called `marked()` which just returns an HTML string.

```
import marked from 'marked';

export default class TranslatedMarkdown extends Component {
  render() {
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: marked(this.props.myMarkdown)}} />
  }
}
```

Comment: The HTML string that you get do you have any new lines that you can split on?

Comment: Yes - it has a new line after each title

Comment: ah - split to array, map over it?

Comment: You could also get fancy with RegEx and map that way, though string split to array and map is much clearer and easier to reason about.